# How to write a calligraphic letter with a check hat?

Tags: math-mode, typography

I would like to typeset

[image]

but

```
$\v{\mathcal{R}}$
```

or

```
$\mathcal{\v{R}}$
```

would not work....

Comment: `\check{\mathcal{R}}`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the preamble, make sure you load `amsmath`:

```
\usepackage{amsmath}
```

Then in your document body you can use:

```
$\check{\mathcal{R}}$
```

To get what you want.

Just in case, if you need examples of more accents:

```
$\dot{\mathcal{R}}$
$\ddot{\mathcal{R}}$
$\hat{\mathcal{R}}$
$\check{\mathcal{R}}$
$\grave{\mathcal{R}}$
$\acute{\mathcal{R}}$
$\tilde{\mathcal{R}}$
$\breve{\mathcal{R}}$
$\bar{\mathcal{R}}$
$\vec{\mathcal{R}}$
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! How does this differ from Manuel's comment above? ;-

Comment: If you don't call the amsmath package, it won't work...
Basically that's the difference.

Comment: I think, Manuel implied that ;-) And that's why he wrote a comment instead of a short answer

Comment: You can mark code in your answer by indenting it by four spaces (or via the ` tick marks before and after for inline code). It would also be nice if you explained what the problem was here

Comment: Carlos, could you at least convert your code in a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228)?

Comment: I think that this answer was perfectly fine as it was when I saw it, not *every* question or answer needs a MWE.  This one is so straightforward that a MWE is overkill.  Also, answers in comments are not answers so the fact that someone posted a solution in a comment (and let's note it was only partial!) does not mean that no-one can post a proper answer.  I added a little extra to hopefully satisfy those not happy with this.  Welcome to the site, Carlos, and I hope that in future we can remedy this unfortunate first impression.  We pride ourselves on being the friendliest StackExchange site.

Comment: @LoopSpace +1 for "We pride ourselves on being the friendliest StackExchange site."  Agree 100%.  This environment makes users want to contribute.

Comment: @LoopSpace Although I wrote the comment about the MWE, I agree with you that it is not needed in this case. But without your additions in the answer, it was really badly written :)